# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

Tags: php

line error:

```
$config = new Config;

$strqury = "SELECT * FROM ", $config->ContasTable , " WHERE Login = ? AND ", $config->PasswdColumn ," = ? AND ", $config->CheckemailColum ," = ?";
echo $strqury;
```

Class config:

```
Class Config{

    public $NameGC = 'Grand Chase SkelletonX'; #Nome do Servidor

    public $ContasTable = 'accounts'; #Nome da tabelas das contas
    public $LoginsColumn = 'Login'; #Nome da Coluna dos Login
    public $PasswdColumn = 'Passwd'; #Nome da Coluna do Passwd
    public $CheckemailColum = 'CheckEmail'; #Nome da coluna do checkemail
}
```

my erro: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize ponto `.` para [concatenar](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.string.php) em PHP e não a vírgula `,`:

```
$strqury = "SELECT * FROM ". $config->ContasTable ." WHERE Login = ? AND ". $config->PasswdColumn ." = ? AND ". $config->CheckemailColum ." = ?";
```

Comment: Obrigado @Felipe,  parei de trabalhar um tempo com php tinha esquecido sobre os .

Comment: @Guilherme se resolver o problema, não esqueça de marcar a resposta como certa, para ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema.